# java search specific attribut name in the xml file

Tags: java, xml

I wouldlike to search in my xml file all attribut (name) without use element tag node :

xml :

```
<test 1><test1/>
<test2> <test2/>
<test 3 id="aaa"> </test3>
<test 5> </test5>
<test 6 id="bbb" name="ijof"> </test6>
```

JAVA :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = builder.parse(new File(path));
root = document.getDocumentElement();

String attribut = root.getAttribute("name");
System.out.println(attribut); // Expected ijof
```

Comment: The next time you should be better prepared. Before you ask your next question you should read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your example XML is not parsable. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you execute your code at least once? I dont't think so. Otherwise you would have surely noticed that your XML cannot be parsed.

There are several flaws in your example XML:

1. No root element.
2. Wrong end tags: It should be `<test1></test1>` and not `<test1><test1/>`.
3. Element names must not contain whitespace and start and end tag must match. It should be `<test5> </test5>` and not `<test 5> </test5>`

Apart of that you can use XPATH to get all elements with a `name` attribute.

Here is a complete example with the XML as a string but this should be irrelevant:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class FindNameAttribute {

  private static final String XML =
    "<root>\n" +
    "  <test1></test1>\n" +
    "  <test2> </test2>\n" +
    "  <test3 id=\"aaa\"> </test3>\n" +
    "  <test4 name=\"4\"/>\n" +
    "  <test5> </test5>\n" +
    "  <test6 id=\"bbb\" name=\"ijof\"> </test6>\n" +
    "  <test7 id=\"bbb\"><child name=\"childname\"/> </test7>\n" +
    "</root>\n";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(XML);

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = null;
    try {
      builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
      StringReader reader = new StringReader(XML);
      InputSource source = new InputSource(reader);
      Document document = builder.parse(source);
      XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
      NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//*[@name]", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
      for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Element el = (Element) nodes.item(i);
        String elementName = el.getTagName();
        String nameAttribute = el.getAttribute("name");
        System.out.println(String.format("Element name: %s, name attribute: %s", elementName, nameAttribute));
      }
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException | XPathExpressionException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
<root>
  <test1></test1>
  <test2> </test2>
  <test3 id="aaa"> </test3>
  <test4 name="4"/>
  <test5> </test5>
  <test6 id="bbb" name="ijof"> </test6>
  <test7 id="bbb"><child name="childname"/> </test7>
</root>

Element name: test4, name attribute: 4
Element name: test6, name attribute: ijof
Element name: child, name attribute: childname
```

The relevant XPATH expression is: `//*[@name]`

- `//`: Looks for every element in the document
- `*`: Placeholder for element name. Each name matches.
- `*[@name]`: The `[]` denotes the predicate. We only want elements with a name attribute.
- `@`: Means the following name is the name of an attribute. Whithout it would be interpreted as an element name

Comment: very clear and perfect answer. Thank you very much !